# Throughput up to 1.2Gbps?

Tags: cisco, firewall, throughput

As everybody know that we have 10/100/1000Mbps port. So I wonder that with 1000Mbps port, we just have maximum throughput at 1000Mbps (1Gbps), but some Firewall product, example Cisco ASA 5515-X, throughput max at 1.2Gbps. May be I get lost in somewhere. Anyone can explain for me?

Link: http://www.cisco.com/c/en_ca/products/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/models-comparison.html

Thank you

Comment: Those device have several 1000Mbs interfaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on the image the device has multiple interfaces. The 1.2Gbps throughput is the total traffic it can process on all ports, not per port.

Answer (score 1):

The throughput for the device is an aggregate total of all ports. You're still limited to the port speed of 1Gb, but the entire device can process up to 1.2Gb of traffic between all ports.